# Creating a self signed certificate on IIS 7 with CN name matching domain name

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl

Is there a way to do so on IIS 7 ? According to here http://hansolav.net/blog/SelfsignedSSLCertificatesOnIIS7AndCommonNames.aspx

it is possible to use IIS 6 resource kit tools here http://hansolav.net/blog/ct.ashx?id=0ee46977-c27c-4929-8205-490c84fd649a&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.microsoft.com%2fdownloads%2fdetails.aspx%3fFamilyID%3d56FC92EE-A71A-4C73-B628-ADE629C89499%26displaylang%3den

except the link is deprecated.

Is there any other way or better can someone know where this resource kit can be found again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All such certificates can be created by using makecert,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bfsktky3(v=VS.80).aspx

It was part of Microsoft .NET 2 SDK, but now available in any Windows SDK, such as

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8279

Comment: thanks will try it though I think original tool can do more like importing in store.

Answer (score 1):

This tool is commonly used to manage certificates

http://sourceforge.net/projects/portecle/

Comment: in my opinion, this is way easier than `makecert` as it provides a graphical ui. creating a certificate is extremely easy - you click to create a new "cert store", then click to "generate new key pair", fill few textboxes and you are done.